# Pandas giving forward day range and not backward and in certain pattern

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, datetime

I am trying to get the 3 days back date in list format. What I did till now is:

```
        datelist = pd.date_range(pd.datetime.today(), periods=3).tolist()
    >>> datelist
    [Timestamp('2018-01-31 20:03:51.068944', freq='D'), Timestamp('2018-02-01 20:03:51.068944', freq='D'), Timestamp('2018-02-02 20:03:51.068944', freq='D')]
    >>> datelist = pd.date_range(pd.datetime.today(), periods=-3).tolist()
    >>> datelist
    []
    >>> datelist = pd.date_range(pd.datetime.today()-1, periods=-3).tolist()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'int'
```

In first I have got the forward dates for 3 days.

But I want to have 3 days backward and not forward but if I do `-3` it gives `[]`. and I am willing to have the days living todays date... means a day before today. But got errors.

I am willing to get the output list in the following format:

```
datelist = ['20180130','20180129','20180128']
```

Kindly, suggest me what I can try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For generate from today by [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) first substract for first day in past and add [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.sort_values.html) with [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
N = 3
datelist = (pd.date_range(pd.datetime.today() - pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=N), periods=N)
              .sort_values(ascending=False)
              .strftime('%Y%m%d'))
```

---

```
datelist = (pd.date_range(pd.datetime.today() - pd.Timedelta(days=N), periods=N)
             .sort_values(ascending=False)
             .strftime('%Y%m%d'))

print (datelist)
['20180130' '20180129' '20180128']
```

---

First answer:

Use `list comprehension`:

```
a = [(x - pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=3)).strftime('%Y%m%d') for x in datelist]
```

---

```
a = [(x - pd.Timedelta(days=3)).strftime('%Y%m%d')  for x in datelist]
print (a)
['20180128', '20180129', '20180130']
```

Or convert to `DatetimeIndex` and substract `Timedelta`:

```
a = (pd.DatetimeIndex(datelist) - pd.Timedelta(days=3)).strftime('%Y%m%d').tolist()
```

---

```
a = (pd.DatetimeIndex(datelist) - pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=3)).strftime('%Y%m%d').tolist()
```

Comment: Are you using my code for generating `datelist` variable?

Comment: Thank you. I would like if you let your previous answers here. The previous edits were awesome too...

Comment: I add it to answer.